# Method named with symbol does not return iterable

Tags: javascript

I can't seem to be able to make a method named with a symbol possible to call.

```js
class Mar {
  sym = Symbol("sym");

  *[this.sym]() {
    yield 1;
    yield 2;
    yield 3;
  }
}

const a = new Mar();
console.log([...a[a.sym]()]);
```

It seems that `Mar#[MarInstance.sym]` is not defined anywhere. What am I missing?

Comment: The reference to `this` in the class declaration is not a reference to the class itself; it's whatever the value of `this` is in the context where the class declaration appears.

Comment: It would help clarify things if you would state whether you want each instance of the class to have its own symbol for the function, and thus its own unique identifier for the generator function, or if instead the symbol should be shared by all instances of the class.

Comment: Shared by all instances I guess

Comment: @Pointy it would require a special binding with `@instance` or something?

Comment: I updated my answer with one possible way to do it. I admit that I'm not 100% sure I know what you're trying to achieve by using a symbol as a method name.

Comment: You cannot define a prototype method with a key that is an instance-specific symbol. Define your symbol outside of the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to create the method explicitly in the constructor (per instance) or explicitly on the prototype if it should be shared:

```
class Mar {
  sym = Symbol("sym");

  constructor() {
    this[this.sym] = function*() {
      yield 1;
      yield 2;
      yield 3;
    };
  }
}
```

To put it on the prototype, you'd have to make `sym` a class property, or something like that, depending on your intentions.

*edit* — if you would prefer to have a single Symbol shared by all instances of the class, then you can use a static class property for the symbol. The syntax is a little clumsy still, but what you *could* do is wrap the class instantiation in a function:

```
const Mar = function() {
  const sym = Symbol("sym");
  class Mar {
    *[sym]() {
      yield 1; yield 2; yield 3;
    }
  }
  Mar.sym = sym;
  return Mar;
}();

let m = new Mar();
console.log([...m[Mar.sym]()]);
```

It's not entirely clear what you're trying to achieve by have a Symbol instance be a way to access a method, but these are ways to do it.

Comment: `sym` is a class property, so what's wrong with my thinking in this case?

Comment: @Misiur no, sym is an *instance* property. Class properties are declared with `:` not `=`.

Comment: @Misiur and note that if you want it on the prototype the mechanism would have to be a little different; I'm not sure how you'd set that up because I'm not sure what your real use case is.

Comment: @Pointy Class properties are declared with `=`. https://javascript.info/class#class-properties

Comment: @52d6c6af read the link you just posted: class fields declared with `=` are not placed on the prototype, they're added to the instance. That makes them public instance properties.

Comment: OK our wires are crossed. The name of the Stage 3 proposal is highly confusing. https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields

Comment: No worries, it's still unclear what the OP really wants to do. Personally I think a single symbol for the class (shared by all instances) makes more sense, but, well, Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Pointy exactly that

Comment: @Misiur also what I said about "class properties" is wrong; I don't know what I was thinking. The sample I added a few minutes ago shows how an ordinary property can be added to the class constructor.

Comment: I will be asking TC39 about this usecase as it is working in your second example, but is not intuitive

Comment: @Bergi if I had the slightest clue what the point of this is, I'd probably come up with a largely different solution overall.

Answer (score 1):

This will position the property on the prototype of objects created using the class, which is probably what you want to do:

```js
const s = Symbol('my symbol')
class MyClass {
  *[s]() {
    yield 1
    yield 2
    yield 3
  }
}

const gops = Object.getOwnPropertySymbols
const o = new MyClass()
console.log(gops(o)) // []
console.log(gops(o.__proto__).map(({description: d}) => d)) // ['my symbol']
```

The following [class field syntax](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) will put a property `s` directly on objects created by the class:

```js
class MyClass {
  s = Symbol('my symbol')
}

const o = new MyClass()
console.log(o.hasOwnProperty('s')) // true
```

Comment: I don't this will work the same way as the code that I *think* the OP was trying to do.  And a "class property" generally means something like "static" in other languages; JavaScript calls instance properties "fields", and that's what `s` is in your second code block. However, that local per-instance symbol is not the symbol used for that generator function placed on the prototype.

Comment: OK, thanks. I didn't know "field" had that definition within the JS spec.

Comment: Still, why it is not possible to have per-instance field with symbol and the method with symbol used as a name?